# Hover image effect CSS

Tags: html, css

I have [this site](http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/). In footer I have a list with social icons.

This is HTML code:

```
<div class="social-list">
   <ul>
      <li id="first"><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri1.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri3.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri4.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri5.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is CSS code for `.social-list`:

```
.social-list {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -92px;
}
```

I want to create an effect hover over the images.

I tried to do that but it is not working:

```
#first:hover {
  background:url("http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/roz1.png");
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't see any ID on the first li on your site. Cache issue ?

Comment: What effect would you like to create?

Comment: Please specifye what kind of effect do you want?

Comment: Then why are you expecting `#first:hover` to match anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are changing the background to the `li` but the image is still on top so it's covering it and you cannot see it.

The idea would be to remove the `img` inside the `li` and work exclusively with the `li` background. Something like this:

```
#first {
    background-image:url('http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri1.png'); 
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#first:hover {
    background-image:url('http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/roz1.png');
}
```

Comment: I added your code but I have the same problem

Comment: Did you remove the image? You'll also need to specify the width/height for the `li` to make it work.

Comment: hovered image not is placed where i need ... does this code to you?

Comment: Check the update on the answer